# Space in OU causing ldap search to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, ldap3

I'm using ldap3 library in python3.9 to get all the members and manager details including manager's displayName and Email of specific AD groups into a list with a loop.

```
conn.search(search_base='OU=Groups,OU=US,DC=local,DC=test,DC=org',
    search_filter='(&(objectClass=group)(cn=AD-GROUP-NAME))',
    attributes=['managedBy','member'],
    search_scope='SUBTREE'
    )
```

I pass the results for each member in the above results into a new search :

```
for entry in conn.entries:
    for member in entry.managedBy:
        conn.search(
            search_base=member.split(",",2)[2], # Removes Fname & LName from distinguishedName
            search_filter=f'(distinguishedName={member})',
            attributes=['sAMAccountName','mail','displayName']
            )
```

The second search works for *most* of the members except where there is a space in on of the OU as below in the manager's distinguishedName:

CN=LName, FName,OU=**Admin Accounts**,OU=Management,OU=US,DC=local,DC=test,DC=org

I have tried to escape this using using \ or \\ even replacing the space with 20 but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a DN, it may be less problematic and more performant to read this object directly, like so:

```
for entry in conn.entries:
    for member in entry.managedBy:
        conn.search(
            search_base=member,
            search_filter='(objectClass=*)',
            search_scope=BASE,
            attributes=['sAMAccountName','mail','displayName']
            )
```

Comment: Thanks. I learnt today that I can use the full DN for the search_base.